# Select Random n rows out of Order By clause

Tags: sql, mysql, laravel, postgresql, eloquent

I keep running into this one over and over again, and seeking if there is a better (much more optimized) way to achieve this.

**Requirement :**
From a table XYZ select a random n rows (n can be one or any number) out of first X rows ordered by updated_at

So, in short I am not looking for just random rows, but random 5 rows among last used 20 rows.

**Reason :**
We do multiple bulk operation and if we just select oldest update value, it will end up in multiple threads doing everything. So, some degree of randomization is needed.

**Current Way :**
At present we do it as follows,

```
SELECT * FROM TABLE ORDER BY updated_at ASC LIMIT 20
```

And then in the APP we use randomization to select random 5 of them.

Which is in-efficient, as we are literally throwing away 15 results that db gave us.

We are talking about almost a million row table here, so solution needs to be scale worthy.

Comment: the in App seems to be in-efficient try to get randomized from the db itself

Comment: Oh well, it does impact actually, because we keep making this query and batch operation every minute or every third minute. So network bandwidth, slight memory usage on app, everything comes into picture.

Comment: Yup, that's why I accepted Erwin's answer below. Sometimes simple stuffs just eludes our mind.

Comment: Agreed. Especially on a phone - I didn't see the answer popping up when I started writing the comment, so by the time I finished, first one was already pointless, second one redundant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a subquery:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM  (
   SELECT * FROM tbl
   ORDER  BY updated_at
   LIMIT  20
   ) sub
ORDER  BY random()
LIMIT  5;
```

Postgres has the function [`random()`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-math.html#FUNCTIONS-MATH-RANDOM-TABLE), MySQL has [`rand()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/mathematical-functions.html#function_rand).

Requires an index on `(updated_at)` to be fast, obviously.

If you actually want to lock selected rows, consider (Postgres only):

- [SELECT FOR UPDATE subquery not respecting LIMIT clause under load](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73966670/select-for-update-subquery-not-respecting-limit-clause-under-load/73967537#73967537)

To optimize performance for generic random selection:

- [Best way to select random rows PostgreSQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8674718/best-way-to-select-random-rows-postgresql/8675160#8675160)

Comment: Quite interesting. Definitely should work on both Mysql and Postgres versions, without much of db impact. Already have complex index on that. Any ideas on how it can be done for Model with Laravel Eloquent. ;)

Comment: I can't comment on Lavarel Eloquent, not using it. You don't need a "complex" index, just the most basic B-tree index on `(updated_at)`, or at least one with `updated_at` as leading index column.

Comment: No worries. Let me start a new question with that then. To keep things clear. This should does the job. Will mark as answer. :)

Comment: @AbhishekAnand So this is what i meant by doing it on your db itself, Also don't post another question, since it may be already existing, here you `$randomRows = YourModel::orderByDesc('updated_at')
    ->limit(20)
    ->inRandomOrder()
    ->limit(5)
    ->get();`

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what you want to do, but maybe it relates to this answer here:
[How to randomly select rows in SQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/580639/how-to-randomly-select-rows-in-sql)

if you want to do updates with these rows, you should use
select * from table mytable where orderstatus='notfilled' FOR UPDATE LIMIT 5;

if you select with FOR UPDATE, other parallel processes that do the same query, do not get the rows locked by the first query.
see here: [When to use SELECT ... FOR UPDATE?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10935850/when-to-use-select-for-update)

you release them when you update and commit or rollback the transaction.

Comment: @user16217248 how is this link-only?

Answer (score 0):

An addition for frequent top-n `select`: since version 11, you can [`include`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-createindex.html#id-1.9.3.69.6) some additional data in the index. So if there aren't too many columns hiding under your `*` and they aren't too [heavy](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-admin.html#FUNCTIONS-ADMIN-DBSIZE), you can trade already quick [index scans](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/index-scanning.html) for even faster [index only scans](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/indexes-index-only-scans.html) with (possibly) *zero* heap fetches - everything gets read from the index alone, without ever having to jump to the actual table: [demo at db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/vGykpZqf)

```
create table "TABLE" (id bigserial, txt text, updated_at timestamp);

insert into "TABLE"(txt,updated_at)
select random()::text, n
from generate_series(now()-'1 week'::interval,
                     now(),
                     '1 second')_(n)
limit 3e5;

create index simple_idx on "TABLE" (updated_at);

explain analyze verbose
SELECT * FROM "TABLE" ORDER BY updated_at ASC LIMIT 20;
```

| QUERY PLAN |
| --- |
| Limit (cost=0.42..1.61 rows=20 width=48) (actual time=0.044..0.050 rows=20 loops=1) |
| Output: id, txt, updated_at |
| -> Index Scan using simple_idx on public."TABLE" (cost=0.42..17800.42 rows=300000 width=48) (actual time=0.043..0.047 rows=20 loops=1) |
| Output: id, txt, updated_at |
| Planning Time: 1.011 ms |
| Execution Time: 0.069 ms |

```
drop index simple_idx;
create index inclusive_idx on "TABLE" (updated_at) include (txt);
vacuum analyze "TABLE";

explain analyze verbose
SELECT txt,updated_at FROM "TABLE" ORDER BY updated_at ASC LIMIT 20;
```

| QUERY PLAN |
| --- |
| Limit (cost=0.42..1.21 rows=20 width=27) (actual time=0.038..0.043 rows=20 loops=1) |
| Output: txt, updated_at |
| -> Index Only Scan using inclusive_idx on public."TABLE" (cost=0.42..11768.42 rows=300000 width=27) (actual time=0.037..0.040 rows=20 loops=1) |
| Output: txt, updated_at |
| Heap Fetches: 0 |
| Planning Time: 0.098 ms |
| Execution Time: 0.058 ms |

I simplified the above to only show the improvement on the core query but as demonstrated in the [fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/vGykpZqf), the `order by random() limit n` wrapper benefits from this just the same.

Comment: This seems equivalent to Index + store clause that many databases provide. It's a great thing actually, but the table is having almost 35 columns, too much overhead for our specific use case.

Comment: @AbhishekAnand If *almost* means 3 below the 35, [they'll all fit fine](https://dbfiddle.uk/3c2UgWsV) - indexes limit is 32 columns. Even if some values are long, PostgreSQL does in-place compression before TOASTing, so long `text` and `json` don't immediately block this option either. Not saying it's plug&play2prod but to me, 10x speedup on my 50M test did sound nice enough to look into. I'm not sure what you refer to as *index+store*. In TSQL there's an equivalent `include`, in Oracle you can only `include` in an IOT (`cluster`). The rest has to just add all columns to the index list.

Comment: [@Markus Winand](https://stackoverflow.com/users/312881/markus-winand) made a nice [compatibility matrix](https://use-the-index-luke.com/blog/2019-04/include-columns-in-btree-indexes#sm-index-include) and a review of the feature.